# Retornar valor para que entre a un condicional php Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, php7

Buenas tardes a todos.

No sé si estoy haciendo bien o si es necesario hacerlo.

Estoy trabajando en un desarrollo con PHP y Codeigniter y tengo dos archivos uno en la carpeta de **Controller** y otro en **Model**; lo que trato de hacer es que en el metodo *generar_link_temporal* de **Controller** genere un token, dependiendo de los valores que le pida, luego vaya a *up_token_login* ubicado en **Model** con los parametros y esta función me actualice esos datos en la base de datos, hasta ahí todo bien, funciona correctamente; pero ahora quiero continuar en *generar_link_temporal* de **Controller** y que me traiga un resultado como que se generó la actualización correctamente.

```html
<?php    
    public function generar_link_temporal($id_usuario, $documento){

        //TRAE EL ID DEL USUARIO Y EL DOCUMENTO DE IDENTIDAD, CONCATENA UN RANDOM DE 7 DIGITOS Y UNA FECHA
        $cadena = $id_usuario.$documento.rand(1,9999999).date('Y-m-d');
        //ENCRIPTA EL RESULTADO PARA MÁS SEGURIDAD Y FORMA EL TOKEN, QUE SE UTILIZARÁ PARA ENVIAR EL CORREO
        $token = sha1($cadena);

        $this->load->model('login_recovery');

        $this->login_recovery->up_token_login($token,$id_usuario);


        if(/* SI SE GENERÓ LA ACTUALIZACIÓN CORRECTAMENTE - ENTRE */){
            $enlace = $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].'/PASS_CRASH/restablecer.php?idusuario='.sha1($documento).'&token='.$token;
            echo $enlace;
            exit;

        }
        else{
            return FALSE;
        }

    }
    
?>
```

Este es el *generar_link_temporal* de **Controller**

```html
<?php

class login_recovery extends CI_Model{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function up_token_login($token,$id_usuario,$val){

        $now  = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        $data = array(
            'T_TOKEN'               => $token,
            'T_CREADO'              => $now
        );

        $this->db->where('T_ID_USUARIOS', $id_usuario);
        $this->db->update('USUARIOS', $data);

    }
}

?>
```

Ese es el **Model**

en la parte del Controller hay un if al final y no sé como traer el $conexion->query($resultado) exitoso, para que entre a ese condicional y me cree lo que está adentro.

Agradezco a cualquiera que me pueda sacar de la duda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
if($this->db->affected_rows()){
            $enlace = $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].'/PASS_CRASH/restablecer.php?idusuario='.sha1($documento).'&token='.$token;
            echo $enlace;
            exit;

        }
        else{
            return FALSE;
        }
```

Esto, era lo que buscaba, muchas gracias.